# Can arrow functions be passed as parameters of repeat()?

Tags: javascript, repeat, arrow-functions

While searching for arrow functions I came across this [example](https://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html#h_8AV6kA9jcD)

```
let labels = [];
repeat(5, i => {
  labels.push(`Unit ${i + 1}`);
});
console.log(labels);
// → ["Unit 1", "Unit 2", "Unit 3", "Unit 4", "Unit 5"]
```

1st, repeat method from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) seems to accept only one parameter `(count)`.

2nd, arrow functions should be written like this: `i = () => {}`, and not `i => {}`

Is this an out of date snippet that doesn't work anyway or should I interpret it in another way?

Comment: the repeat function here is written by the user , and not the string method , and the arrow function syntax is correct , take a look 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Only when the function doesn't expect any parameters, should you use `() =>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `repeat` method mentioned in the article is not `String.prototype.repeat`, but a standalone function defined in the article itself - it's not a built-in function:

> But what if we want to do something other than logging the numbers? Since “doing something” can be represented as a function and functions are just values, we can pass our action as a function value.

```js
function repeat(n, action) {
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    action(i);
  }
}
repeat(3, console.log);
```

The syntax you mention

> arrow functions should be written like this: i = () => {}, and not i => {}

is only true if the arrow function in question is meant to accept exactly zero parameters. An arrow function with one parameter *can* have parentheses omitted from the parameter list. (Two or more parameters require parentheses again)

The snippet you mentioned does indeed work fine:

```js
function repeat(n, action) {
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    action(i);
  }
}

let labels = [];
repeat(5, i => {
  labels.push(`Unit ${i + 1}`);
});
console.log(labels);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an own function of `repeat`, not one of `String`.

In this case, you can pass a function with the wanted signature of arguments to the function.

```js
const
    repeat = (l, fn) => {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) fn(i);
    };

let labels = [];

repeat(5, i => labels.push(`Unit ${i + 1}`));

console.log(labels); // → ["Unit 1", "Unit 2", "Unit 3", "Unit 4", "Unit 5"]
```

Comment: Thanks, good answer. I somehow totally misread the repeat func.

I'd probably replace the declaration of "i" outside the loop and use a let. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. First thing first as you said the repeat built-in function only accept one parameter, so the repeat function used here is not built-in it is user-defined function
2. The arrow function can be written as `i = () => {}` exactly but here it is an anonymous arrow function which means it doesn't require a name, we can also write the repeat function like this:

   `repeat(5, function(i) { labels.push(i) })`

Arrow function looks readable, that's why it has been written  like that.

3. If you're confused about the statement inside the for-loop, so it is that repeat function which is called inside the for-loop

   Maybe it will help.